# Changing size of ScrollView scroll width on horizontal scrolls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make a Horizontal Scroll

Here is my code

```
int frameSize = 140;

for (int i = 0; i < self.handArray.count + 10 ; i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = i * frameSize;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(130, 130);

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImage *image;
   // if (i == 0)
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"halo.png"];
    //else
       // image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self.handArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag = i;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(102, 0, 29, 29);

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteHandBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 120);        
    [view addSubview:imageView];
    if (i != 0)
        [view addSubview:btn];

    [self.handScrollView addSubview:view];
}

[self.handScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(frameSize * (self.handArray.count + 10), self.handScrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Below are the images

[image]

[image]

You can see that i have defined scrollView for a specific region but images get distributed on the whole screen. How can I limit the scrollview scrolling width.

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot of how it is appearing ?

Comment: i am not clear with your question..

Comment: The scroll view is just spreading to whole width of iPhone 320 where i have set it to 280 in XIB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (it's difficult), try

```
self.handScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: dpjanes, thats it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have u try to set the autoresizingMask on xib file??

If not try like in image below:

[image]